# Fréchet differentiation of integral operator on $L^2(0,1)$ or $C[0,1]$

Tags: functional-analysis, frechet-derivative

For an exercise (3.2.27 in P. Drábek, J. Milota, "Methods of Nonlinear Analysis"), I'm trying to differentiate (in the Fréchet sense) this operator
$$ F(\varphi) = \int_0^1 \left[ \int_0^t |\varphi(s)|^2 \text{d}s \right]^3 \text{d}t $$
both for $\varphi \in C[0,1]$ and $\varphi \in L^2(0,1)$.

I'm trying to informally guess an expression for the Fréchet derivative of $F$ using the chain rule and the fact that the derivative of the Volterra operator $V(\psi)(t) = \int_0^t \psi(s) \text{d}s$ (which is well defined both on $C[0,1]$ and $L^2(0,1)$) is given by $V'(\psi)(h) = \int_0^t h(s) \text{d} s$. But I don't know how to deal with the outer integral (can I just bring the differentiation operator inside?) and with the composition of the Volterra operator with the absolute value (or complex modulus) squared.

Can someone give me an idea on how to compute this kind of derivatives? An informal derivation would also suffice, then I would need to verify that this is indeed the Fréchet derivative of $F$ at $\varphi$ by showing that it is linear, bounded, and that it satisfies
$$ \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\lVert F(\varphi + h) - F(\varphi) - F'(\varphi)h\rVert}{\Vert h \rVert } = 0 $$
(the norms are either the $L^2$-norm or the $C^0$-norm, depending on what we're considering to be the domain of the operator).

**Edit:** I think I can introduce the following operators (let's consider the case $C[0,1]$ for the moment):
$$ A : C[0,1] \to \mathbb{R} : \omega \mapsto \int_0^1 (\omega(t))^3 \text{d}t \\
B : C[0,1] \to C[0,1] : \psi \mapsto \int_0^t \psi(s) \text{d} s \\
C : C[0,1] \to C[0,1] : \varphi \mapsto |\varphi|^2,$$
and rewrite $F$ as the composition $A \circ B \circ C$, so that I can apply the chain rule:
$$ F'(\varphi) = A'(B \circ C(\varphi)) B'(C(\varphi)) C'(\varphi). $$
Would this approach work? Can someone help me with these computations?

Comment: I think your best bet here is to just calculate $F(\varphi + h) - F(\varphi)$ manually. Use the fact that $b^n - a^n = (b - a)\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1} b^k a^{n-1-k}$ to change the difference of the cubes into a sum of more manageable terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will handle the case of $C[0,1]$ on the reals.
Firstly split the functional into four parts:

Define
\begin{align} H : C[0,1] &\longrightarrow C[0,1]  \\
\varphi  &\longmapsto \big( s  \mapsto |\varphi(s)|^2  \big),
\end{align}
\begin{align} G : C[0,1] &\longrightarrow C[0,1] \\
\psi  &\longmapsto \big( t \mapsto \psi(t)^3 \big)
\end{align}
and $J : C[0,1] \to \mathbb{K}$ by $J(\psi) = \int_0^1 \psi (t) dt$.
Then clearly $F =  J \circ G \circ V \circ H$. Here $V$ is the Voltera operator. Since $J$ and $V$ are continuous and linear their derivatives are just themselves.

To find the derivative of $G$ let $\psi , \eta \in C[0,1]$. Then
$$
G(\psi + \eta ) - G(\psi) = (\psi + \eta )^3 -\psi^3 = 3 \psi \eta^2 + 3 \psi^2 \eta + \eta^3
$$
from which it follows that $DG(\psi) = M_{3 \psi^2} $, where $M_{3 \psi^2} $ is the multiplication with $3 \psi^2$ operator and $DG(\psi)$ is the derivative of $G$ at $\psi$.

If the underlying field is the real numbers we can compute the derivative of $H$ in the same way to receive $DH(\psi) = M_{2 \psi}$.

The chain rule gives:
$$DF (\psi)= J \circ DG (V H(\psi)) \circ   V \circ DH(\psi) = J M_{3 (V \psi^2)^2} V M_{2\psi}.$$

Inserting all the definitions:
$$ DF(\psi) (\eta) = \int_0^1 \bigg[3\bigg( \int_0^t \psi^2(s) ds \bigg)^2 \int_0^t 2 \psi(s) \eta(s) ds \bigg]dt .$$

Comment: I just edited my question with a similar decomposition of the operator. Thank your for going through all the computations in detail. What if we take $\mathbb{C}$ as the base field? Can I still differentiate operator H? I will think about the $L^2$ case now. With respect to your computations, what should I pay attention to when switching from $C[0,1]$ to $L^2(0,1)$ ?

Comment: @david_sap The different part will be how to show the correct convergence for the derivative of $G$ and $H$ (which i did not do at all). I am not sure right now how to handle the absolute value in the complex case to be honest.